# Download PDF file AJAX POST - ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, pdf, post

I am using AJAX Post (please see below code snippet).

The `generatePD` method generates a PDF file. But I am not sure how to download that pdf file to the browser. I tried to use response but I couldn't get this worked.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "../StoreOperations/Service.asmx/generatePDF",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
I solved it using a form

```
     <form  id="formpdf" method="POST" style="display:none">
         <input name="param1" id="param1" >
          <input name="param2" id="param2" >
    </form>

 url="../StoreOperations/Service.asmx/generatePDF";
 $('#formpdf #param1').val("valor1");
 $('#formpdf #param2').val("valor2");
 $('#formpdf').attr('target', '_blank');
 $('#formpdf').attr("action", url);
 $('#formpdf').submit()
```